# How to disable icon centering in Plasma 5.24.4

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, desktop-background, desktop-icons

I want to make a stylish desktop by making the background interact with the icons, but I search a lot and couldn't find how to disable the icon grid (alignment), only in older versions of Plasma.
Here is exactly what I wanted to do:

[image: What I wanted to do]

The icons are not in the right place because there is a grid that distances each icon so I can only snap to certais points on that grid.

Also, please comment if I forgot to include any output or information. My screen is 1366x768. Thanks